# bundle install and rbx-require-relative

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, bundle

After following [railstutorial.org](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/beginning#sec%3arubygems)I am trying to run `bundle install`. It list use of gem like :

```
Using railties (3.0.7) 
Using rails (3.0.7) 
Using sass (3.1.3)
```

And this error :

```
Installing rbx-require-relative (0.0.5) /home/canard/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:364:in `ensure_required_ruby_version_met': rbx-require-relative requires Ruby version ~> 1.8.7. (Gem::InstallError)
    from /home/canard/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:135:in `install'
...
```

I understand ruby 1.9.2 needs rbx-require-relative, but why it doesn't want to install it. It demand ruby ruby 1.8.7. I am little lost.

Further more after this error it stop, and my gem in my Gemfile are never read or installed...

I'm using ruby 1.9.2p180 and rails 3.0.7

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 95, accepted):

rbx-require-relative is a port of Ruby 1.9’s relative_relative for Rubinus and MRI 1.8

If you're running ruby1.9 then you don't need it. Remove it from your Gemfile.

Don't require ruby-debug in your Gemfile as it has rbx-require-relative as a dependency. 
Add gem 'ruby-debug19' instead

Comment: And add `gem 'ruby-debug19'` instead.

Comment: I wrote the book in question, and I didn't know this. Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

You might try to install the the ruby-debug19 gem for ruby 1.9.2.

Here is the gem info:
http://rubygems.org/gems/ruby-debug19

Here is the bundler line:

```
gem 'ruby-debug19'
```

Answer (score 4):

Replacing

```
gem 'ruby-debug'
```

with

```
gem 'ruby-debug', :platforms => :ruby_18
gem 'ruby-debug19', :platforms => :ruby_19
```

in my Gemfile solved this problem for me, working on both Ruby 1.8 and 1.9.